# Where can i find the VIP package to run on my plsr output?

Tags: vip

I have run a plsr model using the pls package and I would like to calculate VIP(Valuable importance in projection) scores. Does anyone know where I can find the VIP package to calculate the VIP scores? Share a link if you can

I would prefer something that will be compatible with the output from the plsr run from the pls package.

plot_vip <- vip(my_plsr,geom = "point")
*Error in order(x$Importance, decreasing = decreasing) :
argument 1 is not a vector
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `Importance`.*